# Does a window have place for background image like a dialog?

Tags: winapi, dialog

Can you set a background bitmap in a window as in a dialogbox?

what are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows itself doesn't make any direct provision for either one, so I guess to that extent, they're identical. The obvious difference is that in a normal window, it's quite normal for you to draw a bitmap into the background, but in a dialog you should normally only use controls.

To set a background bitmap in a Window, you normally draw that bitmap in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND` (and return TRUE to keep Windows from erasing the background itself).